# Parametros para métodos con servicios Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, animated

quiero utilizar una función para animar un img al hacer poner el ratón sobre el icono, llamada bounce(). Estos iconos se reflejan en un .service de Angular donde se encuentra la ruta de cada icono. Actualmente, he conseguido que realice la animación, pero afecta a todos los iconos, y quiero que los anime de forma individual.

¿Cómo puedo pasarle un parametro a la función dentro del documento .html para que anime solo uno de los iconos en vez de todos a la vez?

HTML:

```
                <table class="table">

                    <div class="col" routerLinkActive="active">
                        <div class="row-4" *ngFor="let about of abouts">
                            <br>
                            <p class='lead mb-5'>
                                <img class="icons" [src]="about.img" [@bouncing]="currentState"> {{about.bio}}
                            </p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </table>
```

TS:

```
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

  // tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name
  constructor( private _AboutService: AboutService,
               private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
               private router: Router) {

                this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe( params => {
                  console.log(params);
                });
}

  currentState = 'normal';
  abouts: About[] = [];
  about: any = {};

/* Here i call the AboutService */

ngOnInit() {
  this.abouts = this._AboutService.getAbouts();
  }

/* this function do that the hobbies icons bounce when the mouse will be over. Then, the currentState var will come back to the original state in 1.5 seconds */

bounce() {

    this.currentState = this.currentState === 'normal' ? '*' : 'normal';
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.currentState = 'normal';
    }, 1500);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que estas bindeando una sola variable del componente a todos los tags "img", al cambiar el valor de esa variable, afecta a todos por igual.

Hay varias soluciones posibles:

1. Crear un componente para cada "img" y recibís el @Input de un objeto About y manejas el "hover" del mouse en ese componente.
2. Utilizás los eventos "mouseenter" y "mouseleave" para aplicar clases CSS a cada IMG. Esta me parece la más simple, a menos que necesites otro tipo de comportamiento.